# Implementing Private Data Collection in Hyperledger Fabric 2.0 Error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I tried to implement the private data collections in fabric 2.0 network.I have faced error when I tried to invoke chaincode with the transient data flag. 
And it is unable to recognize the method ("priv").

```
 Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: transaction returned with failure: Error: You've asked to invoke a function that does not exist: priv"
```

The "priv" method in chaincode is fairly simple.It is using the `putPrivateData()` method to store the private data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it.The issue was related to the version of shim api in package.json of chaincode.